# File isn't being copied after updating copy-webpack-plugin and webpack in React app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

previously dev dependencies:

```
{
  ...
   "webpack": "^4.14.0",
   "webpack-cli": "3.0.8",
   "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.1.3",
   "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.5",
}
```

now updated to

```
{
    ...
    "webpack": "^5.79.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^6.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0"
}
```

In previous version the file was copied

webpack.base.config.js

`new CopyWebpackPlugin([path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/workers/worker.js')])`

now updated

```
new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/workers/worker.js'),
          to: 'workers',
        },
      ],
    }),
```

not being copied at all.

I tried with changing the output folders to "/" or `path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/workers/worker.js')"` still did not work

Answer (score 0):

It is now working after I removed the "to" part

```
 new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/workers/worker.js'),
        },
      ],
    }),
```